# Drawing multiple Images

Tags: c#, optimization, animation

Im trying to draw a lot of fields image for my world generation, all is perfect 64 fps, but if i began to draw all the time the grass it became laggy, like 59 fps (something that musn't happen! :( ), i need help and some tricks to draw things in c# with more optimization :)

```
int loadedChunks = 0;
        for (int chunkX = 0; chunkX < sizeX; chunkX++)
        {
            for (int chunkY = 0; chunkY < sizeY; chunkY++)
            {
                int xChunk = chunkX + CamXCh - 1,
                    yChunk = chunkY + CamYCh - 1;

                long idChunk = xChunk + ((long)yChunk << 32);

                if (allChunks.ContainsKey(idChunk))
                {
                    loadedChunks++;
                    Chunks currentChunk = allChunks[idChunk];
                    List<CeldsChunk> celds = currentChunk.MapChunk;

                    // Draw Ground
                    for(int celdIndex = 0; celdIndex < celds.Count; celdIndex++)
                    {
                        CeldsChunk celd = celds[celdIndex];
                        Point cord = celd.cords;
                        int sizeCL = cord.size,
                            CeldX = xChunk * sizeChunk + CameraX + cord.posX * sizeCL,
                            CeldY = yChunk * sizeChunk + CameraY + cord.posY * sizeCL,
                            sizeCeld = cord.size;

                        Color celdType = celd.type;
                        //SolidBrush brsh = new SolidBrush(celdType);
                        g.DrawImage(grass, new Rectangle(CeldX, CeldY, sizeCeld, sizeCeld));

                        //Image sk = celd.img;
                        //if (sk != null)
                        //    step2.Add(new Point(CeldX, CeldY, sizeCeld), sk);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Step 2  Draw Forest
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Point, Image> s in step2)
        {
            Point kps = s.Key;
            Image ips = s.Value;
            int posX = kps.posX,
                posY = kps.posY,
                siz = s.Key.size,
                w = ips.Width,
                h = ips.Height;

            //g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(posX, posY, siz, siz));
            //g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new Rectangle(posX - (h >> 2) + (siz >> 1), posY - h + siz, w, h));
            g.DrawImage(ips, new Rectangle(posX - (h >> 2) + (siz >> 1), posY - h + siz, w, h));
        }
```

Comment: That's not a lot of code to go on. It looks like you can lift `xChunk * sizeChunk + CameraX` and `yChunk * sizeChunk + CameraY` out of the loop, however.

Comment: okay i change the code

Answer (score 2):

## Naming

What is the difference between `xChunk` and `chunkX`? `yChunk` and `chunkY`? Choose names that will help, not hinder you.

Don't skimp on letters. `size` is better than `siz`, `point` is better than `kps`. Almost anything is better than `step2`. On the other hand, `chunks` is better than `allChunks`, `chunk` is better than `currentChunk`.

Class names are usually singular -- see for instance `Point`, `Color`, `Rectangle`. Follow the pattern and rename `Chunks` to `Chunk`.

The names `Chunk` and `CeldsChunk` don't convey anything to me -- that might be because I have no domain knowledge of what you're doing, or it might be because their names can be improved.

## Commented-out code

It's confusing. Is it a failed attempt? Commented out for performance testing? No-one knows. If you might need it later, save it on a new branch. Otherwise, delete it.

## Conventions

Follow C# conventions. Install StyleCop and listen to its recommendations.

## Performance

Profiling is your best bet. You can try things like moving repeated calculations out of loops, as I suggested in the comment, but it's possible you're just asking too much of the computer. You're drawing up to `sizeX * sizeY * ?` images, and the solution might be to make do with fewer images.

Comment: I know dat my code is not too easy to read but i think this is not the problemn at all, i will fix the names, but i appreciate your time tx.